# Accessing each color channel of a color() in Processing 3

Tags: colors, processing

In Processing 3, given a variable of type `color` which stores a color, how would one access each individual color channel?

For example, given the following code:

```
color c = color(200, 100, 50);
int r, g, b;
```

I want to extract each of the R, G, and B values from `c` and store them in `r`, `g`, and `b` respectively, such that:

```
r == 200
g == 100
b == 50
```

The Processing 3 reference for `color()` does not outline any methods of extracting these color channels (see https://processing.org/reference/color_.html).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ... a variable with color() ... you created a ... program with get() ... and we are supposed to know what you are talking about?

Comment: What type is the variable returned by `color()`? [Color Class?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

Comment: @Johnny Mopp: It's stored like this: `color(r, g, b, a);`. Not sure though. @Stultuske: Using `get(x, y)` will return the color of that pixel.

Comment: Are you "storing the RGB in an array" or using [`java.awt.Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)?

Comment: I’m currently storing it as java.awt.Color, but I want it to be stored as an array (first parameter is R, second is G, third is B, fourth is transparency).

Comment: The fact that you’re using java.awt.Color is important information that should have been included in your question.  No one knows what you’re talking about when your question only mentions the word “color” without explaining your current implementation.

Comment: I didn’t know that before though :/ I’m using an app for iOS that will auto define it if it’s not the right data type. Since I didn’t know what it was, I just called it as “var” and let it fix it for me. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The second part of the question may be a separate question, but once you have the components, putting it in an array should be simple.  Also note [`Color.darker()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#darker--) and [`Color.brighter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#brighter--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`java.awt.Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) has methods specifically to get each component

```
int a = color.getAlpha();
int r = color.getRed();
int g = color.getGreen();
int b = color.getBlue();
```

If using [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), using a bitmask may be easier

```
int c = color.getRGB(); //or image.getRGB(x, y)
int a = (c & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
int r = (c & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
int g = (c & 0xFF00) >> 8;
int b = c & 0xFF;
```